# Overriding MVC DefaultModelBinder to handle arrays of complex objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

The default MVC model binder (`System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBiner`) correctly binds the following syntax of nested arrays:

```
 array[0].propertyA=valueA&array[0].propertyB=valueB& ...etc
```

To the following action method:

```
 public ActionResult AjaxHandler(Part[] array, ...)
```

However, jQuery.param() is only able to serialize into the following syntax :

```
 array[0][propertyA]=valueA&array[0][propertyB]=valueB& ...etc
```

Setting `traditional` flag to true still produces incorrect mapping:

`array=[object+Object]&...etc`

I was checking out DefaultModelBinder.cs but that class is something like 900 lines of code and would take quite some time to dissect.

I'm looking for some pointers on which members to override or an implementation would be even more appreciated.

Comment: The default model binder is great at parsing JSON, any reason you don't want to use JSON?

Comment: Not sure, you haven't provided enough of what you're trying to accomplish in terms of models or jQuery to fully understand what you are doing.