# Using [FromUri] attribute - bind complex object with nested array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I want to send a complex object with a nested array **in the uri** to an MVC action method in a GET request.

Consider the following code:

```
 public ActionResult AutoCompleteHandler([FromUri]PartsQuery partsQuery){ ... }

 public class PartsQuery
 {
     public Part[] Parts {get; set; }
     public string LastKey { get; set; }
     public string Term { get; set; }
 }

 $.ajax({ 
    url: "Controller/AutoCompleteHandler", 
    data: $.param({                                        
                      Parts: [{ hasLabel: "label", hasType: "type", hasIndex : 1 }],
                      LastKey : "Last Key",
                      Term : "Term"                             
                   }),
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(jsonData) { ... }
 });
```

This works just fine and binds correctly using the default model binder **in MVC Web Api**.

However, switch this to plain MVC not WebApi and the default model binder breaks down and cannot bind the properties on objects in the nested array:

**Watch List**

```
partsQuery      != null          //Good
--LastKey       == "Last Key"    //Good
--Term          == "Term"        //Good
--Parts[]       != null          //Good
----hasLabel    == null          //Failed to bind
----hasType     == null          //Failed to bind
----hasIndex    == 0             //Failed to bind
```

I would like to know why this breaks down in plain MVC and how to make `FromUriAttribute` bind this object correctly in plain MVC

Comment: What happens if you change `Part[] Parts` to `ICollection<Part> Parts`?  And can you show the class definition for `Part`?

Comment: Trying that now. Part is simple POCO with public { get; set; } props

Comment: Does `Part` have a parameterless constructor?

Comment: ICollection didn't fix the binding issue. It previously did not have a parameterless constructor but I just tried with one and still no go (tried with ICollection).

Comment: Is this Ajax call still required to be a `Get`?

Comment: yes Erik, must be GET. I'll use the regex in my comment unless someone can solve the underlying issue of makign `FromUriAttribute` work with MVC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Core issue here is that MVC and WebApi use different model binders. Even base interfaces are different.

```
Mvc - System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder
Web API - System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder
```

When you send data with your $.ajax call, you are sending following query string parameters:

```
Parts[0][hasLabel]:label
Parts[0][hasType]:type
Parts[0][hasIndex]:1
LastKey:Last Key
Term:Term
```

While, proper format that would bind with MVC default model binder has different naming convention for parameter names:

```
Parts[0].hasLabel:label
Parts[0].hasType:type
Parts[0].hasIndex:1
LastKey:Last Key
Term:Term
```

So, this method call would work:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "Controller/AutoCompleteHandler?Parts[0].hasLabel=label&Parts[0].hasType=type&Parts[0].hasIndex=1&LastKey=Last+Key&Term=Term",
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function(jsonData) { ... }
});
```

You need to construct your query string respecting MVC model binder naming conventions.

Additionally `[FromUri]` attribute in your example action is completely ignored, since it's not known to MVC DefaultModelBinder.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I already knew that much. 2 possible solutions would be to coerce the url string into the correct convention on the client side, my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580471/javascript-regex-to-coerce-url-string-returned-from-param-into-mvc-model-bindi , OR make a custom model binder to handle the default $.param() convention, my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17558735/1267778.. But I'm thinking the cleanest solution might be to make MVC support FromUri, which is what this question is for. If nobody can answer that I will mark your answer

Comment: Regex is a sufficiently clean solution so I'll mark yours as answer because it's valuable nonetheless. But if someone can actually answer the real question of how to make FromUri work in MVC I'll mark that. Thanky ou

Comment: I think making Web API binding work in MVC controller would be huge effort. Pipelines are completely different and to invoke Web API binding you would have to instantiate properly bunch of lower-level web-api specific objects (HttpControllerDescriptor, HttpActionDescriptor, ModelBindingContext, etc).