# Javascript Regex to coerce url string returned from $.param into MVC model binding convention

Tags: javascript, regex

The following jQuery code:

```
 $.param({                                        
                  Parts: [{ hasLabel: "label", hasType: "type", hasIndex : 1 }],
                  LastKey : "LastKey",
                  Term : "Term"                             
         })
```

gives the following output:

```
 "Parts%5B0%5D%5BhasLabel%5D=label&Parts%5B0%5D%5BhasType%5D=type&Parts%5B0%5D%5BhasIndex%5D=1&LastKey=LastKey&Term=Term"
```

which decodes to (using decodeURI()) :

```
 "Parts[0][hasLabel]=label&Parts[0][hasType]=type&Parts[0][hasIndex]=0&LastKey=LastKey&Term=Term"
```

However, the default model binder in MVC expects the following:

```
 "Parts[0].hasLabel=label&Parts[0].hasType=type&Parts[0].hasIndex=0&LastKey=LastKey&Term=Term"
```

I'm looking for a Javascript Regex to coerce **the encoded** string into a (still encoded) string , but one that decodes to the correct model binding convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
var params = "Parts[0][hasLabel]=label&Parts[0][hasType]=type&Parts[0][hasIndex]=0&LastKey=LastKey&Term=Term";
var mvcParams = params.replace(/\[([^0-9]+)\]/g,'.$1');
```

EDIT:

To work on an encoded string do the following:

```
var params = "Parts%5B0%5D%5BhasLabel%5D=label&Parts%5B0%5D%5BhasType%5D=type&Parts%5B0%5D%5BhasIndex%5D=1&LastKey=LastKey&Term=Term";
var mvcParams = params.replace(/%5b([^0-9]+)%5d/gi,'.$1');
```

Comment: cr@p, really sorry but I just realized that I actually needed this to work on the encoded string, aka the return value of `encodeURI("Parts[0][hasLabel]=label&Parts[0][hasType]=type&Parts[0][hasIndex]=0&LastKey=LastKey&Term=Term")`. Need to coerce the result of that into something such that `decodeURI(result) == "Parts[0].hasLabel=label&Parts[0].hasType=type&Parts[0].hasIndex=0&LastKey=LastKey&Term=Term"`

Comment: I've just tested it and it works! How it works? with your expression, shouldn't be replaced everything between [ ]? what's the meaning of '.$1' (a link to the definition will be apreciated)...

Comment: @parliament: if you call encodeURI on the variable mvcParams above you will get the desired result

Comment: @ESt3b4n: go here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace and search for the description of $n

Comment: Yes but thats just unneccesary processing because i have to send the encoded version so I would have to do encodeURI(decodeURI($.param(data)).replace(regex)) instead of $.param(data).replace(regex)

Comment: To be fair, so was the first answer, you just changed the question after i had answered it the first time ;)